# Compute average on each rows and store in the last element

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, average

I need to compute the average of each row and store in the last element. I managed to do but the subsequent rows are the accumulated average from the previous row. 
eg:

input:

1 2 3 0

4 5 6 0

output:

1.00 2.00 3.00 2.00

4.00 5.00 6.00 **7.00** (This should be 5.00)

Here is my code

```
   void findAverage2D(float matrix[4][4])
     {    
       int i,j = 0;
       float sum,avg=0;

       for(i=0;i<4;i++)
     {
        for(j=0; j<4;j++)
        {
            sum+= matrix[i][j];
        }
        avg = sum/3;
            matrix[i][3] =avg;

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You should set `sum` to `0` after you have calculated `avg`.

Comment: You should set `sum` to `0` before you started inner for loop.

Comment: you should set `sum` to '0' as the first statement of the for-i loop. At the moment it's nor guaranteed that `sum` is 0.0 in the beginning.

Comment: Whitespace is cheap. Please use it to improve readability.

Comment: i knew it got something to do with the sum. Thank you people!

Comment: Besides that, I think you should limit your inner loop to j < 3, because you are using the last element to store the average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move variable "sum" inside first for loop -

```
 for(i=0;i<4;i++)
 {
    float sum = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two bugs in the function.

The first one is that the variable `sum` initially is not initialized and neither initialized in each iteration of the outer loop.

The second bug is that the last element of each row should not take part in the calculation of the average.

Taking this into account the function can look the following way

```
    void findAverage2D( float matrix[][4], size_t n )
    {
        const size_t M = 4;

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            float sum = 0.0f;
            for ( size_t j = 0; j < M - 1; j++ )
            {
                sum += matrix[i][j];
            }
            matrix[i][M-1] = sum / ( M - 1 );
        }
    }
}
```

The function must be called with two arguments where the second argument is the number of rows in a given array.